# Eclipse - Errors running builder on project

Tags: eclipse

I was getting this error constantly in eclipse:

> Errors during build. Errors running builder "Integrated External Tool
>   Builder" on project  project. The builder launch configuration could
>   not be found. Errors running builder "Integrated External Tool
>   Builder" on project  project. The builder launch configuration could
>   not be found.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I added this question and answering on my own as I could not find an answer on Stackoverflow and it may benefit someone else

Answer is:

> On your project "project", right click -> Properties>Builders Remove
>   the missing builder

Source
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/28894/

Comment: Thank you. I only had to change the path variable to the workspace instead of removing the builder.

Comment: @Gezzasa could you please provide some details on how to do that?

Comment: @Sumit I would love to. This was quite long ago however and I haven't been using a setup like this since then. Sorry.

From what I recall though. I was working on a windows machine and my %path% variables weren't set up correct (I think)

Answer (score 11):

You can follow these steps.

1. Select the right project.
2. Choose "project"on the tool bar -> Properties
3. Click "Builders" on the menu of the popped up window
4. Remove the missing builders

[Reference links](http://jibeex.blogspot.com/2011/05/eclipse-error-builder-launch.html)

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue,

> "Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project
>   {PROJECT NAME}"

you must go to your .project file in your work space, and you can put in comment or delete this lines

```
<buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
            <triggers>full,incremental,</triggers>
            ...
            ...

</buildCommand>
```

and after that, you can rebuild your project and it will work correctly.

Reference: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=118294

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this happened after fiddling with existing builders (e.g. renaming them) and the solution was to restart Eclipse (Neon.3 v4.6.3).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove missing builders from this location
**Right click on project->properties->Builders**
Remove all missing builders

Answer (score 0):

Adding the builder ( for example : in my case java builder) in *.project* file  of the error getting project worked for me.