# My ANT build is not creating a .class file

Tags: java, ant

I currently have an existing ANT build file w/c supposedly exports .java file and a .class file.

Somehow it does export the .java files with changes but the .class files doesn't seem to work.

I'm using this for the Syclo Agentry java changes.

```
<!-- ====================================================================== 
 SMART-SAP - Copy java to devserver folder

 rev. DSA 7/18/11                                                                
 ====================================================================== -->
```

```
<description>
        Upload Syclo files to dev server
</description>

<property name="sapRoot"    value="F:\ATE\Kurt\Project Files\R2"/>
<property name="root"       value="F:\ATE\Kurt"/>
<property name="server"     value="${root}\CRM Server R2"/>
<property name="javaFolder" value="${server}\Java"/>

<property name="servicemanagerBinFolder" value="${sapRoot}\S4SAP-ServiceManager\bin"/>
<property name="stockBinFolder"          value="${sapRoot}\S4SAP-Stock\bin"/>


<target name="CopyClasses" description="Copy class files" >
    <copy todir="${javaFolder}" verbose="true" overwrite="false">
        <fileset dir="${servicemanagerBinFolder}" />
        <fileset dir="${stockBinFolder}" />
    </copy>
</target> 

<target name="CompileClasses" description="Compiles class files">
        <javac destdir="${javaFolder}/src/" classpathref="classpath"      
         failonerror="true"> 
            <src path="${servicemanagerBinFolder}"/>
        </javac>
</target>
</project>
```

Okay so I've added the code for it to compile... though I'm getting an error saying that the path was not specified

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'S4SAP-ServiceManager'.
Location not specified by New_Builder
Location not specified by New_Builder

Comment: Your only task is one to *copy* files. There's nothing here to perform any compilation...

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the info! How can I go about doing that? Or if you can point me to the link when I can learn this that is great as well.

Comment: Well, I'd start off reading the Ant documentation, to be honest... http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html

Comment: @Kevin something like `<javac srcdir="../${projectName}/src" destdir="dist/classes" ><classpath refid="externalJars" /></javac>`

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

Comment: @alex thanks ill try to read on ANT building thanks for the guide

Comment: @alex what does the <classpath refid=""> do? What do I put in there?

Comment: @Kevin `classpath` provides an option to add external jars to your classpath when compiling with `<javac>`, where `externalJars` has been defined as a `<path>`. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path for additional information and examples. Alternatively you could use `classpathref`, as per manual.

Comment: @alex thanks. I've updated the code and it's giving me an error idk what i'm doing wrong this time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382062/eclipse-errors-running-builder-on-porject